# Finding Standard Deviation of Continous Distribution

Tags: statistics

> $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ are continuous Uniform(0, 1) distributions.
>
> $S_4 = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4$
>
> Find $SD(S_4)$

[image]

[image]

Answer should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Formula for the variance is wrong.  You want the mean of the square minus the **square** of the mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula of variance should be

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(X)^\color{red}{2}$$

Hence you shall end up with

$$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^4\left( \frac13-\frac14\right)}=\sqrt{4 \cdot \frac1{12}}=\frac1{\sqrt3}$$